# Bash for loop treat all files at once instead of one after another

Tags: bash, csv, for-loop

I'm facing a weird issue and can't figure out where its from

I have 2 similar functions :

```
TMP_DIR="/tmp/folder"
OUTPUT_DIR="output"

func1()
{
   for file in `ls $TMP_DIR/*_INPUT_VLAN.csv`
   do
     local hostname=$(echo $file | awk -F '_INPUT' '{print $1}' | cut -d "/" -f 4)
     OUTPUT=$(echo $hostname"_net_conf.txt")
     IFS=";"
     cat $file | sed '1d' | while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8
     do
       echo "some things with $f1 $f2 .." >> $OUTPUT_DIR/$OUTPUT
     done
   done
}

func2()
{
   for file in `ls $TMP_DIR/*_INPUT_ROUTES.csv`
   do
     local hostname=$(echo $file | awk -F '_INPUT' '{print $1}' | cut -d "/" -f 4)
     OUTPUT=$(echo $hostname"_net_conf.txt")
     IFS=";"
     cat $file | sed '1d' | while read f1 f2 f3 f4
     do
       echo "some things with $f1 $f2 .." >> $OUTPUT_DIR/$OUTPUT
     done
   done
}
```

My input files look like this :

file1 : HOSTNAME1_INPUT_VLAN.csv

```
int;type;vxid;name;id;ip;mask;comment
int1;int;0;vlan1;1;192.168.1.1;255.255.255.0;VLAN Network 1
int2;ext;1;vlan2;1;192.168.2.1;255.255.255.0;VLAN Network 2
int3;int;2;vlan3;1;192.168.3.1;255.255.255.0;VLAN Network 2
```

file2 : HOSTNAME2_INPUT_VLAN.csv

```
int;type;vxid;name;id;ip;mask;comment
int1;int;0;vlan1;1;192.168.1.1;255.255.255.0;VLAN Network 1
int2;ext;1;vlan2;1;192.168.2.1;255.255.255.0;VLAN Network 2
int3;int;2;vlan3;1;192.168.3.1;255.255.255.0;VLAN Network 2
```

file1 : HOSTNAME1_INPUT_ROUTES.csv

```
Network;Interface;Gateway;Comment
0.0.0.0/0;int1;gateway1;Comment 1
net_1;int2;gateway2;Comment2
net_2;int2;gateway2;Comment2,1
net_3;int3;gateway3;Comment3
```

file2 : HOSTNAME2_INPUT_ROUTES.csv

```
Network;Interface;Gateway;Comment
0.0.0.0/0;int1;gateway1;Comment 1
net_1;int2;gateway2;Comment2
net_2;int2;gateway2;Comment2,1
net_3;int3;gateway3;Comment3
```

When I run the script, the first function succeed but it looks like the second one is not doing the for loop and try to cat both files at once :

```
cat: '/tmp/folder/HOSTNAME1_INPUT_ROUTES.csv'$'\n''/tmp/folder/HOSTNAME2_INPUT_ROUTES.csv': No such file or directory
```

If I had some echos in the functions to see what happens, I see that both files are proceed at the same time

```
func1()
{
  for file in `ls $TMP_DIR/*_INPUT_VLAN.csv`
  do
    local hostname=$(echo $file | awk -F '_INPUT' '{print $1}' | cut -d "/" -f 4)
    OUTPUT=$(echo $hostname"_net_conf.txt")
    echo "Hostname for $file will be : $hostname"
    echo "Ouput for $file will be located in : $OUTPUT_DIR/$OUTPUT"
  done
}

function2()
{
  for file in `ls $TMP_DIR/*_INPUT_ROUTES.csv`
  do
    local hostname=$(echo $file | awk -F '_INPUT' '{print $1}' | cut -d "/" -f 4)
    OUTPUT=$(echo $hostname"_net_conf.txt")
    echo "Hostname for $file will be : $hostname"
    echo "Ouput for $file will be located in : $OUTPUT_DIR/$OUTPUT"
  done
}
```

Output :

```
Hostname for /tmp/folder/HOSTNAME1_INPUT_VLAN.csv will be : HOSTNAME1
Ouput for /tmp/folder/HOSTNAME1_INPUT_VLAN.csv will be located in : output/HOSTNAME1_net_conf.txt

Hostname for /tmp/folder/HOSTNAME1_INPUT_ROUTES.csv
/tmp/folder/HOSTNAME2_INPUT_ROUTES.csv will be : HOSTNAME1
HOSTNAME2
Ouput for /tmp/folder/HOSTNAME1_INPUT_ROUTES.csv
/tmp/folder/HOSTNAME2_INPUT_ROUTES.csv will be located in : output/HOSTNAME1
HOSTNAME2_net_conf.txt

cat: '/tmp/folder/HOSTNAME1_INPUT_ROUTES.csv'$'\n''/tmp/folder/HOSTNAME2_INPUT_ROUTES.csv': No such file or directory
```

Both functions do the for loop in the same why, I don't get why the func2 doesn't proceed as excepted.

I find a workaround by listing files in directory, storing in a tmp file and reading the tmp file with a while loop though, but I wanna know why the original for loop is not not working

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`func1` sets IFS to `;` so the output of `ls $TMP_DIR/*_INPUT_ROUTES.csv` in `func2` isn't being split on newlines anymore. IFS controls how word splitting is performed so you need to be very careful when modifying it.

Some general recommendations:

- [Don't parse ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use globs instead.

```
  for file in "$TMP_DIR"/*_INPUT_VLAN.csv ; do
    ...
  done
```

- Try to localize your IFS changes using scoped environment variables or subshells where possible. For example if you just need IFS changed for your while-loop then use this. The change to IFS will be limited to your read command this way.

```
cat $file | sed '1d' | while IFS=';' read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8
     do
       echo "some things with $f1 $f2 .." >> $OUTPUT_DIR/$OUTPUT
     done
```

- Run your script through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to look for common issues. It will highlight many common issues like the ls parsing problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Didn't knew for the scope of IFS delimiter. This + parsing globs instead of ls works like a charm. Added shellcheck to my favorites, awesome recommandation !

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to the use of a pipe `|` in the `cat` command within the `while` loop of the second function `func2()`.

Pipes create a subshell which runs separately from the main shell, and any variables declared inside it are not available outside.

Therefore, the `$OUTPUT` variable is not being set properly in the outer shell, and instead of redirecting to a file with the expected name, it's redirecting to a file with the name of both `$hostname` variables concatenated.

To fix this, you can try replacing the pipe `|` with `<` in the `cat` command, like this:

```
while IFS=";" read f1 f2 f3 f4; do
  echo "some things with $f1 $f2 .." >> "$OUTPUT_DIR/$OUTPUT"
done < "$file"
```

This will redirect the input of the while loop to come from the file specified by `$file`, rather than from a subshell created by the pipe.

Also, it's generally recommended to use `$(command)` instead of backticks for command substitution, so you can consider replacing ls `$TMP_DIR/*_INPUT_VLAN.csv` with `$(ls $TMP_DIR/*_INPUT_VLAN.csv)` and similarly for the other commands that use backticks.

Hope It helps

Comment: `OUTPUT` is declared before the `cat | while` construct in the first example of `func2` so it exists in the proper scope there, and there isn't a while loop in the second example.

Comment: I think it had mostly to do with the IFS delimiter, changed that ! Thanks !

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).